# Calling specific Python script in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, python

I'm working on a project trying to turn on/off the light in my room using a webpage. I've created this Python script which reads a file to get the state of the light (on or of) and then writes the 'opposite' back to the file. (this would basically toggle the light) If I now call this script in PHP with

```php
system("python script.py")
```

it doesn't output anything to the page instead of the expected state (on or of)

```py
f = open("lightState.txt", "r")
var = f.read(2)
f.close()


f = open("lightState.txt", "w")

state = ""


if(var == "of"):
    #turn light on
    state ="on"

if(var == "on"):
    #turn light off
    state = "of"

print(state)
f.write(state)
f.close()
```

I've also tried this with another Python script in the same folder which worked perfectly fine.

Comment: `system("/path/to/your/python /path/to/the/script.py");` or maybe it's the missing `;`

Comment: There can be multiple issues:


Python path might not be set(Happens in windows), try using full path of python executable. You can find it by running `which python` or `which python3` and use full paths like: `system ("/usr/bin/python file/path/here.py");`


Your .py file might not be accessible to php. If you are running php in terminal then make sure you own both files, if running from web server(like apache/nginx or full wamp setup) then make sure all files are owned/got-previlages to `www-data`

Comment: I'm actually on a rapberry pi running apache2. The path should be fine as php can run files (including python) from the same directory without a problem. I'M gonna try giving it privileges now.